# Retrieve newly created Term tid

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I've created a PHP program outside Drupal that inserts Terms into my Drupal installation.

```
define('DRUPAL_DIR', __DIR__);

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$autoloader = require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/autoload.php';
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->boot();

require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/database.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/schema.inc';


$term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::create([
      'vid' => 'subject',
      'langcode' => 'en',
      'name' => 'Test af Tag',
      'description' => [
        'value' => '<p>My description.</p>',
        'format' => 'full_html',
      ],
      'weight' => -1,
      'parent' => array(0),
])->save();

var_dump($term);
```

My question is - how do I retrieve the newly created Term tid?
The var_dump only gives a

> string(9) "SAVED_NEW"

Why on earth doesn't it return the newly created Entity/Term?!?

I need it in case there will be a child Term later.
I've looked at www.drupal.org/documentation and api.drupal.org. But those pages just confuses me more :-(

Thank you very much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why on earth doesn't it return the newly created Entity/Term?!?

Why would it? You already have the term object, why do you need it to be chained in a return from a save method that can and does provide you with extra context??

Just use this:

```
$term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::create([
  'vid' => 'subject',
  'langcode' => 'en',
  'name' => 'Test af Tag',
  'description' => [
    'value' => '<p>My description.</p>',
    'format' => 'full_html',
  ],
  'weight' => -1,
  'parent' => array(0),
]);

$inserted_or_updated = $term->save();

$tid = $term->id();
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I learn a new important thing today. :-)